# Collision avoidance (AI)

Tags: xna-4.0, ai, geometry

Now my 3D model has complete AI behaviours, but my model has no collision avoidance while he is moving towards the player! Because of this, he gets stuck in front of 3D blocks sometimes.

I think the solution includes the usage of rays.  I've included a picture of what I want to do.

NOTE: The world is a 3D world, not a 2D one.  (Even though they are almost the same)

I want my model to not collide with the boxes while he is moving towards me, i.e make some collision avoidance. :)

[image]

Comment: Aren't you looking for pathfinding?

Comment: Code Assassin , I want my model while is moving toward me ( seek ) just not collide with the models , i.e make some collision avoidance :)

Comment: So he's just continually finding a path to you

Comment: @ssb, yes!! i think you know more than me what do you think

Comment: @ssb , I just want to avoid 3d models ( house , rock , mountine .....etc ) while enemy moving toward me I just want him to not get stuck in the way

Answer (score 3):

A couple people have mentioned pathfinding, but that's only necessary for complex paths, like navigating a maze. Your situation just calls for basic obstacle avoidance so full fledged pathfinding is overkill (plus you often need obstacle avoidance in addition when doing pathfinding anyway). Look on this page for some great examples of steering behavior: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/

In the list of demos you'll notice "Obstacle Avoidance". All you need to do is that, plus make your AI tend to turn toward the player when no obstacle is in the way. The site may have sample code to look at, but simply reading the description is probably gonna help you the most http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Obstacle.html

In essence all it's doing is a box intersection check ahead of the moving entity (a raycast with a wide radius would do too) and if another object is intersected then the entity turns.

Comment: This steering and obstacle avoidance is all you need !

Comment: Only if assuming the domain has very specific traits.  This is difficult to ascertain based only on the phrasing of the question.

Comment: The phrasing sure, but that's why he included a diagram. The diagram makes it pretty clear what kind of obstacles he's talking about.

Comment: @jhocking , thanks brother  I  think you know what I mean , I just need to avoid houses while enemy moving toward me not more.